"Unacceptable TLS certificate" Python Playwright sync mode
I receive this error using Playwright with Python in sync mode.
I found some solutions but only for async mode.
webkit = playwright.webkit
browser = await webkit.launch(headless=False)
context = await browser.new_context(ignore_https_errors=True)
page = await context.new_page()
await page.goto("http://example.com")
...
await browser.close()

I tried this for sync mode
webkit = playwright.webkit
browser = webkit.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context(ignore_https_errors=True)
page = context.new_page()
page.goto("http://example.com")
...
context.close()
browser.close()

But it did not work, and I got an error saying that "ignore_https_errors=True" is an invalid parameter.
